# Como hago para que no se pueda dividir por cero?

Tags: python

Estoy realizando un proyecto en python el cual es una calculadora que hace las operaciones básicas de multiplicación, división, suma, y resta. El problema es que quiero evitar que se pueda dividir por cero, y con este código funciona, pero si introduces una letra y luego pones el cero la condición no se ha aplica y divide entre cero dando así error el programa. ¿Como podría solucionar esto?

```
resp="S"
while resp=="S":
  
  numero1=input("¿Que número eliges como primer número?")
  while not numero1.isdigit():
    print("Tienes que escribir un número")
    numero1=input("Que número eliges como primer número?")
  numero1=int(numero1)
    
  numero2=input("¿Que número eliges como segundo número?")
  while not numero2.isdigit():
    print("Tienes que escribir un número")
    numero2=input("¿Que número eliges como segundo número")
  numero2=int(numero2)

  op=input("¿Que tipo de operacion quieres realizar? (+ - / ó *)")
  while op not in ["+","-","/","*"]:
    print("Tienes que escribir + - / ó *")
    op=input("¿Que tipo de operacion quieres realizar? (+ - / ó *)")
  
  if op=="+":
    print(numero1+numero2)

  elif op=="-":
    print(numero1-numero2)

  elif op=="*":
    print(numero1*numero2)

  elif op=="/":
    while numero2==0:
      print("No se puede dividr por cero, elige otro número")
      numero2=input("¿Que número eliges como segundo número?")
      while not numero2.isdigit():
        print("Tienes que escribir un número")
        numero2=input("Que número eliges como segundo número?")
    numero2=int(numero2)
    print(numero1/numero2)

  resp=input("¿Quieres seguir jugando? (S/N)")
  while resp not in ["S","s","N","n"]:
      print("Tienes que escribir S o N")
      resp=input("¿Quieres seguir jugando? (S/N)")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando ves repetirse las mismas líneas de código es hora de transformar eso en una función. En este caso, haremos una función que ingrese y valide un numero entero. Además tendrá un parámetro opcional que indique si se acepta el valor cero (es `True` por default).

```
def ingresar(lugar, admite_cero = True):
    valor = None
    while not valor:
        try:
            numero = input(f"¿Que número eliges como {lugar} número?")
            valor = int(numero)
            if valor == 0 and not admite_cero:
                print("Cero no es válido")
        except ValueError:
            print("Tienes que escribir un número")
    return valor
```

Para validar que sea un entero, usamos el truco de intentar convertirlo con `int()`, y si eso falla, atrapar la excepción y repetir el ingreso.

La función retorna el valor convertido a entero.

Luego, lo conveniente es pedir la operación primero y luego el segundo valor. Sabiendo la operación podemos pedir el segundo valor chequeando que sea distinto de cero en el caso de la división:

```
resp = "s"
while resp == "s":
    numero1 = ingresar("primer")
    op = input("¿Que tipo de operacion quieres realizar? (+ - / ó *)")
    while op not in ["+", "-", "/", "*"]:
        print("Tienes que escribir + - / ó *")
        op = input("¿Que tipo de operacion quieres realizar? (+ - / ó *)")
    numero2 = ingresar("segundo", op != "/")

    if op == "+":
        print(numero1 + numero2)
    elif op == "-":
        print(numero1 - numero2)
    elif op == "*":
        print(numero1 * numero2)
    elif op == "/":
        print(numero1 / numero2)

    resp = input("¿Quieres seguir jugando? (S/N)").lower()
    while resp not in 'sn':
        print("Tienes que escribir S o N")
        resp = input("¿Quieres seguir jugando? (S/N)")
```

produce:

```
¿Que número eliges como primer número?10
¿Que tipo de operacion quieres realizar? (+ - / ó *)+
¿Que número eliges como segundo número?4
14
¿Quieres seguir jugando? (S/N)n

Process finished with exit code 0
```